# Signing installer of my program generated by Inno Setup to make it of a trusted company?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, code-signing, sign, signtool

I have a installer file created with Inno Setup of an application that I developed.

So when I go to install the program, it shows me a window telling me that my application is not trusted.

How can I sign my installer file to avoid that window when a user installs my program, or to make my installer a trusted installer?

I have a .pfx file that I generated with OpenSSL and my SSL certificate.
I tried signing it with the Inno Setup signing tool but without success. 
This is the line on my signing window:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "C:\Users\user\Documents\programtoinstall\Installers\key.pfx" /p "passwordOfThePfxFile"  /tr "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode" $f
```

Comment: *"without success"* means what? Did you get any error?

Comment: "without success" mean that  my installer or my application its not sign in with my .pfx file.

Answer (score 2):

Signing an installer with a self-signed certificate won't have any effect.

You have to sign the installer with a code signing certificate issued by a trusted authority.

Comment: i have the the .pfx file, but when i go to properties, sign in. And select the .pfx file. Then, show me a window, say it that my certify its not valid it sign in the code. Choose another certify file.

Comment: Where did you get the .pfx file? What Properties > Sign in? Where?

Comment: the .pfx file i obtain by buy it on 1and1.com.

Comment: I do not think that 1&1 sells code signing certificates. You have likely bought SSL certificate. + You didn't answer my other question.

Comment: We have a certificate from Symantec. The same certificate is used on our server for ssl security and work well. This is a list of the files from Symantec: file.pfx , certificate_intermediate.cer, private_key.key

Comment: A certificate is issued for a certain purpose. A certificate issued for SSL cannot be (in general) used for a code signing and vice versa. + You still didn't answer my other question.

Comment: Just like you say, after many searches, i found that my certificate its not valid to code signing.